# QGIS Advanced Python Field Calculator Error: File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'DN is not defined

Tags: qgis, python

I am using the advanced python field calculator to change the numeric values from a field "DN" to text using the following script:

```
def getValue(DN):
if DN == '10':
    value = 'undifferentiated urban'
elif DN == '11':
    value = 'Urban'
elif DN == '12':
    value = 'Commercial'
elif DN == '13':
    value = 'Major Roads'
elif DN == '20':
    value = 'Undifferentiated Cropland'
elif DN == '21':
    value = 'Cropland'
elif DN == '30':
    value = 'Undifferentiated Cutblocks'
elif DN == '31':
    value = 'Graminoid Cutblock'
elif DN == '32':
    value = 'Shrubby Cutblock'
elif DN == '33':
    value = 'Tree Cutblock'
elif DN == '40':
    value = 'Undifferentiated Burn'
elif DN == '41':
    value = 'Graminoid Burn'
elif DN == '42':
    value = 'Shrubby Burn'
elif DN == '43':
    value = 'Treed Burn'
elif x == '44':
    value = 'New Burn'
elif DN == '51':
    value = 'Closed Black Spruce'
elif DN == '52':
    value = 'Closed Jack Pine'
elif DN == '53':
    value = 'Closed White Spruce'
elif DN == '54':
    value = 'Closed Undifferentiated Conifer'
elif DN == '55':
    value = 'Closed Deciduous'
elif DN == '56':
    value = 'Closed Coniferous Leading Mixedwood'
elif DN == '57':
    value = 'Closed Deciduous Leading Mixedwood'
elif DN == '58':
    value = 'Closed Mixwood'
elif DN == '61':
    value = 'Closed Shrub'
elif DN == '63':
    value = 'Closed Upland Shrub'
elif DN == '71':
    value = 'Fescue Grassland'
elif DN == '72':
    value = 'Mixed Grassland'
elif DN == '81':
    value = 'Emergent Wetlands'
elif DN == '82':
    value = 'Graminoid Wetlands'
elif DN == '83':
    value = 'Shrubby Wetlands'
elif DN == '85':
    value = 'Lichen Bog'
elif DN == '86':
    value = 'Black Spruce Bog'
elif DN == '88':
    value = 'Undifferentiated Wetland'
elif DN == '91':
    value = 'Water'
elif DN == '101':
    value = 'Permanent Ice and Snow'
elif DN == '102':
    value = 'Rock Talus'
elif DN == '103':
    value = 'Exposed Soil'
elif DN == '105':
    value = 'Upland Dune Field'
elif DN == '112':
    value = 'Cloud'
elif DN == '113':
    value = 'Haze Shadow'
elif DN == '152':
    value = 'Open Pine'
elif DN == '153':
    value = 'Open Spruce'
elif DN == '154':
    value = 'Open Undifferentiated Conifer'
elif DN == '155':
    value = 'Open Deciduous'
elif DN == '163':
    value = 'Open Shrub'
else:
    value = 'none'
return value
```

However, I get the following log error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\FieldPyculator.py", line 176, in processAlgorithm
exec(bytecode, new_ns)
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'DN' is not defined

Execution failed after 0.03 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Advanced Python field calculator' finished

Eventually, I would like to include this script at the tail end of a graphical modelling task I've completed.  The field name "DN" will be the same as well.

[image: Advanced Py Field Calculator Parameters]

[image: Log Error]

Comment: I think that field names in Python Field Calculator must be written between the <> symbols. Please try with `value = getValue(<DN>)` to see if it works that way.

Comment: Joining lookup table will do the same work with 10 times less efforts.

Answer (score 1):

As requested, please find the final code and screenshot:

```
def getValue(DN):
    if DN == 10:
        value = 'undifferentiated urban'
    elif DN == 11:
        value = 'Urban'
    elif DN == 12:
        value = 'Commercial'
    elif DN == 13:
        value = 'Major Roads'
    elif DN == 20:
        value = 'Undifferentiated Cropland'
    elif DN == 21:
        value = 'Cropland'
    elif DN == 30:
        value = 'Undifferentiated Cutblocks'
    elif DN == 31:
        value = 'Graminoid Cutblock'
    elif DN == 32:
        value = 'Shrubby Cutblock'
    elif DN == 33:
        value = 'Tree Cutblock'
    elif DN == 40:
        value = 'Undifferentiated Burn'
    elif DN == 41:
        value = 'Graminoid Burn'
    elif DN == 42:
        value = 'Shrubby Burn'
    elif DN == 43:
        value = 'Treed Burn'
    elif DN == 44:
        value = 'New Burn'
    elif DN == 51:
        value = 'Closed Black Spruce'
    elif DN == 52:
        value = 'Closed Jack Pine'
    elif DN == 53:
        value = 'Closed White Spruce'
    elif DN == 54:
        value = 'Closed Undifferentiated Conifer'
    elif DN == 55:
        value = 'Closed Deciduous'
    elif DN == 56:
        value = 'Closed Coniferous Leading Mixedwood'
    elif DN == 57:
        value = 'Closed Deciduous Leading Mixedwood'
    elif DN == 58:
        value = 'Closed Mixwood'
    elif DN == 61:
        value = 'Closed Shrub'
    elif DN == 63:
        value = 'Closed Upland Shrub'
    elif DN == 71:
        value = 'Fescue Grassland'
    elif DN == 72:
        value = 'Mixed Grassland'
    elif DN == 81:
        value = 'Emergent Wetlands'
    elif DN == 82:
        value = 'Graminoid Wetlands'
    elif DN == 83:
        value = 'Shrubby Wetlands'
    elif DN == 85:
        value = 'Lichen Bog'
    elif DN == 86:
        value = 'Black Spruce Bog'
    elif DN == 88:
        value = 'Undifferentiated Wetland'
    elif DN == 91:
        value = 'Water'
    elif DN == 101:
        value = 'Permanent Ice and Snow'
    elif DN == 102:
        value = 'Rock Talus'
    elif DN == 103:
        value = 'Exposed Soil'
    elif DN == 105:
        value = 'Upland Dune Field'
    elif DN == 112:
        value = 'Cloud'
    elif DN == 113:
        value = 'Haze Shadow'
    elif DN == 152:
        value = 'Open Pine'
    elif DN == 153:
        value = 'Open Spruce'
    elif DN == 154:
        value = 'Open Undifferentiated Conifer'
    elif DN == 155:
        value = 'Open Deciduous'
    elif DN == 163:
        value = 'Open Shrub'
    else:
        value = 'error'
    return value
```

[image: Advanced Python field calculator screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The error were as follows:

1. It looks like it was an indentation error at the return value
2. There was an x == '44': instead of DN == '44':

However,

The results field in the attribute table now has all values = none

Comment: You are comparing numeric value with string, remove ' around them.

Comment: It works wonderfully now.  Thank you.  I have learned what those ' ' are to be used for now.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the Advanced Python Field Calculator dialog with the code that work?